# Does a replacement exist for Dexter? (A tool that reconstructs data from a pdf of a graph)

Tags: data-analysis, raw-data, modeling

Dexter was a tool from the German Astrophysical Virtual Observatory, made by the Center for Astronomy of Heidelberg University (ZAH). It was able to reconstruct data from a graph if you provided a pdf or an image of that graph. It relied on Java, and since browsers have stopped support for Java it no longer works.

Website for reference: https://dc.zah.uni-heidelberg.de/dexter/ui/ui/custom

Does anyone know of another tool that does the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see the discussion https://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2011/11/17/digitize-that-figure-fast/

Comment: Thanks James, I'll give it a read!

Comment: I used Dexter too.

Comment: I wonder whether you could use the [applet viewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) solution that Oracle provides...

Answer (score 2):

You question reminded me of a tool I first encountered in the 80’s (I know right!) called “data thief”. Back when Mac applications had a four letter “creator code” this one had the code “DIEF” (which is the Dutch word for “thief”).

I appears to be around still - and as it doesn’t rely on a browser it may well still work (I haven’t tried in years though).

Take a look [here](https://datathief.org)